# Can't sent headers after they are sent on express Troubleshooting

Tags: node.js, http, express, http-headers

Got problem with express and this code :

```
    appToken.post('/getToken', function(req, res) {
        console.log("Got one request to have a token");
        console.log("cookie : "+req.headers.cookie);
        
        wp_auth.checkAuth( req ).on( 'auth', function( auth_is_valid, user_id ) {
            if(auth_is_valid){
                //genToken();
                console.log("[ACCEPTE] Création d'un token pour la connection de "+user_id)
                var token = jwt.sign({ "userId" : user_id }, appToken.get("cert"), { "subject" : "ChatAuthentification"});
                res.status(200).json({"token": token});
                return;
                
            }else{
                console.log("[ERREUR] Utilisateur non valide");
                res.status(401).json({error: "Connexion refusé. Vous êtes-vous connecté sur le site Wordpress ?"});
                return;
            }
            
        });
    
});
```

On the first connection, everithing is good, he will send the response etc.
On the second connection, even with the .json method, who have to close the connection, i have the following problem :

"can't set headers after they are sent"

How can i go through this ?

## EDIT

HEre is the part used of the wp_auth module, created first by nightGunner5 and i've modified to make it work on wordpress 4.0 (and his new authentification process) :

```
function WP_Auth( wpurl, logged_in_key, logged_in_salt,
                mysql_host, mysql_user, mysql_pass, mysql_db,
                wp_table_prefix ) {
    var md5 = crypto.createHash( 'md5' );
    md5.update( wpurl );
    this.cookiename = 'wordpress_logged_in_' + md5.digest( 'hex' );
    this.salt = logged_in_key + logged_in_salt;

    this.db = require( 'mysql-native' ).createTCPClient( mysql_host );
    this.db.auth( mysql_db, mysql_user, mysql_pass );
    this.table_prefix = wp_table_prefix;

    this.known_hashes = {};
    this.known_hashes_timeout = {};
    this.meta_cache = {};
    this.meta_cache_timeout = {};

    // Default cache time: 5 minutes
    this.timeout = 300000;
}

WP_Auth.prototype.checkAuth = function( req ) {
    var self = this, data = null;
    if ( req.headers.cookie ) // s'il y a des cookies 
        req.headers.cookie.split( ';' ).forEach( function( cookie ) { // separation de chaque cookie
            if ( cookie.split( '=' )[0].trim() == self.cookiename )
                data = cookie.split( '=' )[1].trim().split( '\|' );
        } );
    else
        return new Invalid_Auth();

    if ( !data )
        return new Invalid_Auth();

    if ( parseInt( data[1] ) < new Date / 1000 )
        return new Invalid_Auth();

    return new Valid_Auth( data, this );
};

exports.create = function( wpurl, logged_in_key, logged_in_salt,
                mysql_host, mysql_user, mysql_pass, mysql_db,
                wp_table_prefix ) {
    return new WP_Auth( wpurl, logged_in_key, logged_in_salt,
                mysql_host, mysql_user, mysql_pass, mysql_db,
                wp_table_prefix );
};

function Invalid_Auth() {}
Invalid_Auth.prototype.on = function( key, callback ) {
    if ( key != 'auth' )
        return this;
    var self = this;
    process.nextTick( function() {
        callback.call( self, false, 0 );
    } );
    return this;
};

function Valid_Auth( data, auth ) {
    var self = this, user_login = data[0], expiration = data[1], token = data[2], hash = data[3];

    if ( user_login in auth.known_hashes_timeout && auth.known_hashes_timeout[user_login] < +new Date ) {
        delete auth.known_hashes[user_login];
        delete auth.known_hashes_timeout[user_login];
    }

    function parse( pass_frag, id ) {
        var hmac1 = crypto.createHmac( 'md5', auth.salt );
        hmac1.update( user_login +'|'+ pass_frag + '|'+ expiration + '|' + token);
        var hmac2 = crypto.createHmac( 'sha256', hmac1.digest( 'hex' ));
        hmac2.update( user_login + '|' + expiration + '|' + token );
        if ( hash == hmac2.digest( 'hex' ) ) {
            self.emit( 'auth', true, id );
        } else {
            self.emit( 'auth', false, 0 );
        }
    }

    if ( user_login in auth.known_hashes )
        process.nextTick(function() {
            parse( auth.known_hashes[user_login].frag, auth.known_hashes[user_login].id );
        } );

    var found = false;
    auth.db.query( 'select ID, user_pass from ' + auth.table_prefix + 'users where user_login = \'' + user_login.replace( /(\'|\\)/g, '\\$1' ) + '\'' ).on( 'row', function( data ) {
        found = true;
        auth.known_hashes[user_login] = {frag: data.user_pass.substr( 8, 4 ), id: data.ID};
        auth.known_hashes_timeout[user_login] = +new Date + auth.timeout;
    } ).on( 'end', function() {
        if ( !found ) {
            auth.known_hashes[user_login] = {frag: '__fail__', id: 0};
            auth.known_hashes_timeout[user_login] = +new Date + auth.timeout;
        }
        
        parse( auth.known_hashes[user_login].frag, auth.known_hashes[user_login].id );
    } );
}
```

Comment: `"can't set headers after they are sent"` is caused by trying to send a response more than once to the same request.  It is usually caused by improper handling of the timing of async callbacks, but I don't see that type of issue in the code you have disclosed.  I'm guessing there's more to this issue than just the code you've disclosed.

Comment: Well, i've try with another computer, when i alternate the request by this way : A - B - A - B..., everithing seems to be alright. It's just when the same user try to redeem a token.

Comment: What's happening in `wp_auth.checkAuth()`?  Can  you include that code?  Any chance it triggers the auth event more than once in some circumstances?  Or that you're adding a duplicate event handler somehow?

Comment: I've updated all of this

Comment: It looks to me like `parse()` can be called more than once which means that the `self.emit( 'auth', ...)` can be called more than once which means that your request handler will try to send the response more than once because it gets the `auth` event more than once for a given request.  I think maybe you need a `return` statement if this conditional `if ( user_login in auth.known_hashes )` is true so you don't get to the next `parse()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like `parse()` can be called more than once which means that the

```
self.emit( 'auth', ...)
```

can be called more than once which means that your request handler will try to send the response more than once because it gets the `auth` event more than once for a given request.  I think maybe you need a `return` statement if this conditional `if ( user_login in auth.known_hashes )` is true so you don't get to the next `parse()`.

Change this:

```
if ( user_login in auth.known_hashes )
    process.nextTick(function() {
        parse( auth.known_hashes[user_login].frag, auth.known_hashes[user_login].id );
    });
```

to this;

```
if ( user_login in auth.known_hashes ) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        parse( auth.known_hashes[user_login].frag, auth.known_hashes[user_login].id );
    });
    return;
}
```